# parLapply from inside function copies data to nodes unexpectedly

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have a large list (~30GB) and functions as follows:

```
cl <- makeCluster(24, outfile = "")

Foo1 <- function(cl, largeList) {
  return(parLapply(cl, largeList, Bar))
}

Bar1 <- function(listElement) {
  return(nrow(listElement))
}

Foo2 <- function(cl, largeList, arg) {
  clusterExport(cl, list("arg"), envir = environment())
  return(parLapply(cl, largeList, function(x) Bar(x, arg)))
}

Bar2 <- function(listElement, arg) {
  return(nrow(listElement))
}
```

There are no issues with:

```
Foo1(cl, largeList)
```

Watching the memory usage for each process I can see that only one list element is being copied to each node.

However, when calling:

```
Foo2(cl, largeList, 0)
```

a copy of largeList is being copied to each node.  Stepping through Foo2, the largeList copying is not happening at clusterExport, but rather on parLapply.  Also, when I execute the body of Foo2 from the global environment (not within a function), there are no issues.  What is causing this?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 21 (Twenty One)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[7] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9-7           zoo_1.7-12          snow_0.3-13        
[4] Rcpp_0.12.2         randomForest_4.6-12 gbm_2.1.1          
[7] lattice_0.20-33     survival_2.38-3     e1071_1.6-7        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] class_7.3-13 tools_3.2.2  grid_3.2.2
```

Comment: What OS, and what is your makeCluster call?

Comment: OS is Fedora 21.  I edited the question to include the makeCluster call and sessionInfo

Comment: I believe that, regardless of OS, the default cluster type is PSOCK vs FORK. This is what I use for clusters in packages: `if (grepl("Windows", sessionInfo()$running)) {cl <- makeCluster(nnodes, type= "PSOCK")}
    else {cl <- makeCluster(nnodes, type= "FORK")}` ... can you confirm your cluster type is using forking?

Comment: I called summary(cl) and each node is of type "SOCKnode."

Comment: Can you try re-running your example with fork nodes instead and see if htat solves your problem? If that's sufficient, I'll move my comments to an answer.

Comment: I tried calling makeForkCluster and my usual code wouldn't work, giving the error "no applicable method for senddata applied to an object."  However replacing parLapply with mclapply (which uses forking) makes Foo2 work.  This does solve my problem but I'm still curious what is causing the data copying issue.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the worker function, which is the third argument to `parLapply`, is serialized and sent to each of the workers along with the input data. If the worker function is defined inside a function, such as `Foo2`, then the local environment is serialized along with it. Since `largeList` is an argument to `Foo2`, it is in the local environment, and therefore serialized along with the worker function.

You didn't have a problem with `Foo1` because `Bar` was presumably created in the global environment, and the global environment is never serialized along with functions.

In other words, it's a good idea to always define the worker function in the global environment or in a package when using `parLapply`, `clusterApply`, `clusterApplyLB`, etc. Of course, if you're calling `parLapply` from the global environment, the anonymous function is defined in the global environment.

Comment: Is there any other way to define the worker function inside `Foo2` without serializing all objects created in `Foo2`?

Comment: You can maybe change the environment of the function to be e.g. `baseenv()`.