# Running parLapply and future_map inside another function unnecessarily copies large objects to each worker

Tags: r, parallel-processing, r-future, furrr

I was looking for an alternative to `furrr:future_map()` because when this function is run inside another function it copies all objects defined inside that function to each worker regardless of whether those objects are explicitly passed (https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr/issues/26).

It looks like `parLapply()` does the same thing when using `clusterExport()`:

```r
fun <- function(x) {
  big_obj <- 1
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
  parallel::clusterExport(cl, c("x"), envir = environment())
  parallel::parLapply(cl, c(1), function(x) {
    x + 1
    env <- environment()
    parent_env <- parent.env(env)
    return(list(this_env = env, parent_env = parent_env))
  })
}

res <- fun(1)
names(res[[1]]$parent_env)
#> [1] "cl"      "big_obj" "x"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How can I keep `big_obj` from getting copied to each worker? I am using a Windows machine so forking isn't an option.

Comment: On windows, you have to copy the data. The only way to not copy the data is to not have any data at all. Meaning, store it on disk and load only a subset to work on.

Comment: I came across this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851761/parlapply-from-inside-function-copies-data-to-nodes-unexpectedly?rq=1. It seems the issue I describe has to do with defining the worker function inside another function instead of the global environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the environment of your local function so that it does not include `big_obj` by assigning e.g. only the base environment.

```
fun <- function(x) {
  big_obj <- 1
  cl <- parallel::makeCluster(2)
  on.exit(parallel::stopCluster(cl), add = TRUE)
  parallel::clusterExport(cl, c("x"), envir = environment())
  local_fun <- function(x) {
    x + 1
    env <- environment()
    parent_env <- parent.env(env)
    return(list(this_env = env, parent_env = parent_env))
  }
  environment(local_fun) <- baseenv()
  parallel::parLapply(cl, c(1), local_fun)
}
res <- fun(1)
"big_obj" %in% names(res[[1]]$parent_env) # FALSE
```